# Express js, Add trailing "/" to all urls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this express js code in my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var publicdir = __dirname + '/client';

app.set('port', 8080);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path.indexOf('/js/') === -1 && req.path.indexOf('/css/') === -1) {
        if (req.path.substr(-1) === '/') {
            req.url = req.url.slice(0, -1) + '.html';
        } else {
            res.redirect(301, req.url + '/');
        }
    }
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(publicdir, {
    extensions: ['html', 'htm']
}));
```

I'm trying to make the urls render consistently to always have a trailing "/" at the end of every URL. While the above code works I am keep getting error messages in my log file saying:

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

This error comes from a url pattern like this:

`http://www.myserver.com/my-page-name`

But it does correctly add the trailing "/" to the end.

How can I change the above code to eliminate that log error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you call `res.redirect()`, do NOT call `next()` because that will allow your other route handlers to process the URL resulting in the error message you see as two route handlers both try to send a response.

Change your middleware handler code to this (leave the rest of your code as is):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path.indexOf('/js/') === -1 && req.path.indexOf('/css/') === -1) {
        if (req.path.substr(-1) === '/') {
            req.url = req.url.slice(0, -1) + '.html';
        } else {
            // redirect to add the slash, do not continue routing
            res.redirect(301, req.url + '/');
            return;        // returning here will skip the call to next() below
                           // so there will be no additional routing
        }
    }
    // continue routing if we get here
    next();
});
```

The idea is that you want to call `next()` in all code paths that do not issue `res.redirect()`, but not in any code path that does.

Comment: Ah ha! That's the key. I changed the `next()` to `done()` instead and not it's working properly WITHOUT the log error! Thank you!

Comment: @tonejac - I don't know where you got a `done()` from, but I'm glad it's fixed now.

Comment: When I removed the next() call the server just hung and would not serve the page. Adding done() did the trick. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @tonejac - There is no `done()` in the code you show or in express.  Not sure where you got that from.  I call `next()` in two places in my code.  You need it in both places.  I suspect you didn't implement my suggestion correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I was referencing `next()` in my app.use function but I suppose there is not next function that exists in my server file, so it was just hanging.

Comment: @tonejac - `next` comes from the first line `app.use(function(req, res, next) {`.  It's an argument passed to your middleware handler.  You really need to know how this stuff works to use it correctly and write solid code.

Comment: @tonejac - I've simplified my answer.  I'm really not sure what you think you're doing in the answer you supplied - that is not correct.

Comment: Ahhh. That makes sense. I’ll try out that modification.

Comment: I've seen people use the pattern of `return res.redirect(...)` (or `return res.send(...)`) so that you don't accidentally keep doing stuff after resolving the request.

Comment: @Coderer - That pattern is not my favorite because it's a coding style that implies there's a meaningful return value from the function (when there isn't).  I prefer to put an empty `return;` on the line following the `res.redirect()`.  But, either works just fine.

Comment: I don't think this will work in many cases because `req.url` is sometimes not a URL that the client sees (if you are behind a reverse proxy) and also, in many cases, an expressjs router will give you `/` instead of the full path. You could try parsing `req.originalUrl` but that has a querystring as well...

Comment: @Marc - This works just fine for the specific problem in the question being asked here.  The situations you are speaking about are different situations than what is being asked here.  `req.url` in a top level router will show the path of the request that the server received and that's what this question wants to make decisions based on.  If you've configured a proxy that changes the URL, then of course, you have to code your server to react to the paths that IT will receive - that's a given.

Comment: @Marc - If you're using a non-top level router, then you with look at `req.originalUrl` to see the whole path or you code your router to deal with the relative path segment that it will be expecting.  And, none of this has anything to do with the question here.

Comment: I'm not nixing your answer - but you are making a lot of assumptions in your comments. Does OP say he's not behind a reverse proxy? Even if it works for him, lots of folks will google the same problem, land here and, like me, it won't work for them for the reasons I've given. Hence the tip.

Comment: @Marc - The problem in the question (as I understood it) was an issue with sending multiple responses to the same request which results in "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.".  That is the problem that I helped them with and my advice solved their issue.  I did not attempt to rewrite the rest of their code for other possible issues.  If you think there is a better answer to be offered that covers the things you want to see covered, please add your own answer.